# How to save user data in an iPhone login type app

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data, persistence

Im developing an iPhone app with user logging design and i am trying to understand how to save user data and app state for each user in the same iPhone.
For example suppose my app flow is as follow:
1. user log in.
2. app gets the user friends list from core date and present it. 
3. in the background the app fetch the user friend list from a server and update core data.

Now suppose there are two users that simultaneity uses the app with the same iPhone
how can i know witch data to load from core data to each user? haw can i know witch app state to return to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it seems important to pose the question of why you are trying to do this in the first place.  As I'm sure you have noticed, Apple designed the iPhone to be a single user device.  This is why you don't see their apps (and generally apps from 3rd parties as well) allowing multiple users.

That said, if you are absolutely sure you want to do this, then you clearly need to give the user some ability to change user accounts.  You're never going to know when one person is using the phone over another, so you have to provide the ability to switch users similarly to how fast user switching works in OS X.

Anyway, you probably need to start by creating an additional Core Data entity called "User".  That entity should contain information about each user (name, nickname, photo, etc).  Then you need to create a relationship from the "User" entity to whatever entities you are using to store your friends list.

You'll need to decide what the behavior of the app will be.  Will the current user automatically be logged out when the app quits?  Hard to say as you don't know who is going to use the app next.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, my app is for a single user like all apps with user login&password design, sorry its hard for me to explain my problem so ill try to use an example: suppose after the user logging to the app he can upload profile picture, and this picture is saved to a file called "userPicture". now this user log out and his friend logging with the same phone, now my app will load "userPicture" but this is the previous user picture and not the current logged in user picture. (the picture is just an example, the same thing with friend list or any user data)

Comment: Ya, I understand what you are saying.  You need to arrange your Core Data model to allow for a multi-user environment.  Like I said - you need to create a new entity to hold users.  Then add relationships from each instance of a user entity to the instances of the entities holding friends lists, etc.  Each time a new user logs in, you pull up the correct user's data by traversing the relationship between the User entity and the entity holding the friends list.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a core data entity for users and link the entries in it with the friend list entries. Therefore every user should have a unique identifier. Also in your friendlist entity there should be a key like "userId" to hold the reference to the user.